# I get "unknown attribute 'password' for User." error while runing User.create on rails consol

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to create User using
User.create ({email:"ayzabc66@gmail.com", password:"password",password_confirmation:"password"})

but I keep on getting below error:
/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activemodel-7.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in `_assign_attribute': unknown attribute 'password' for User. (ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError)

I have already uncommented gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"   and ran bundle.

This is what my user.rb looks like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    #email :string
    #password_digest:string
    #password:string
    #password_confirmation:string virtual
    has_secure_password
end
```

And my db>migrate looks like:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the following in Rails Console, do you get the list of attributes that you would expect?

```
=> User
```

If so, I would try uncommenting the lines that you have in your `User` model and see if that helps, so it would look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    email :string
    password_digest:string
    password:string
    password_confirmation:string virtual
    has_secure_password
end
```